# Merge the tags [windows-store-apps] and [windows-store]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I think the tags [windows-store-apps](/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) (751 questions) and [windows-store](/questions/tagged/windows-store) (105 questions) should be merged. Almost half (47) questions tagged [windows-store](/questions/tagged/windows-store) are also tagged [windows-store-apps](/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps); the remaining questions don't seem to be specifically about the Windows *Store*, as opposed to Windows Store *apps*.

Because of the greater specificity, I think it would make sense to also delete [windows-store](/questions/tagged/windows-store).